# What is the thing that

Tags: riddle

My question is:

> What is the thing which reduces weight when you wet and increases weight when you dry?

Comment: reduces weight?

Comment: Just to make sure: *decreases* is no typo for *increases*, right ?

Comment: sulphur (OR) sugar

Comment: @Evargalo, you are right. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand, how is you being wet or dry influencing that object in any way? maybe you meant when it is wet and when it is dry?

Comment: I am wondering.. 6 answers to puzzle but -3 votes to question? even one answer has 4 upvotes?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if your choice of wording in this riddle is intentional, but

> If read in a specific way, the answer could be anything used by anyone which gets wet when used and is left to dry afterwards, like a towel or a sponge.

Because

> It reduces weight *after* wet (when left to dry) and increases weight *after* dry (when first used/re-used)

Now after your edit, again sticking to exact wording, it could be

> Your body, which reduces weight *when you wet* (are sweaty from exercising, or when urinating) and increases weight *when you dry* (stop exercising enough, or have problems urinating)

Answer (score 1):

as @narasimha mentioned it, 
it can be

> sulphur

as

> It has a specific gravity of 2. That means if we weigh it under water, it would have an perceptible weight less than its original.

Comment: And what about **increasing**?

Comment: @IQWANTER  if weigh under water it weigh less, so if weigh dry, the weight obviously increases, right

Answer (score 1):

I think we are talking about

> [Apparent weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_weight)

From that point of view any object that is:

> Submerged in water, i.e. wet will have higher apparent weight due to the buoyancy and will be heavier when out of the water, i.e. dry.

Comment: I thought the same and was going to write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't seen this as an answer so what about:

> A Water Butt

Because

> When a Water Butt is used to water the garden, therefore wet, it loses weight as it loses water

But

> When the water butt is not being used to water the garden and is therefore dry, because it is not providing water, the water butt becomes heavier as it continues to store any further rainwater.

Answer (score 1):

This can be

> the clouds above you

They lose weight

> when it's raining, making you wet

They gain weight

> after the rain, when they form again (water condensation), letting you dry

Similarly, this could also be

> your water tank that empties when you take a shower and that fills up once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Far-fetched

> A campfire or a flame

What is the thing which reduces weight when you wet and increases weight when you dry?

> [Fire has a 'weight'](http://www.askamathematician.com/2012/04/q-how-much-does-fire-weigh/) 
>  You put out a campfire by adding water. 
>  If there were wet logs in the campfire, they will dry out and fuel the flames.